# Prove $\frac{a}c = \frac{a-b}{b-c}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose  $\frac{1}a,\frac{1}b,\frac{1}c$ are three consecutive terms in an arithmetic sequence. Show that:

$$\frac{a}c = \frac{a-b}{b-c} $$

and that:

$$\frac{2ac}{a+c} = b$$
How would I prove this?

Comment: Hint: if $x,y,z$ are three consecutive terms of an arithmetic sequence, then $y-x = z-y$.

Comment: Hint for the second one:if x,y,z are three consecutive terms of an arithmetic sequence, then x + z = 2y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have ${1 \over b} = {1 \over 2} ({1 \over a} + {1 \over c})$. This leads to
$$b = {2ac \over a + c}$$
Substitute this in...

Comment: Boom. Nicely handled; +1. Simplest method for this part of the question I guess...

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{a}{c}=\dfrac{a-b}{b-c}\impliedby ab-ac=ac-bc\impliedby \color{red}{ab+bc=2ac}\impliedby\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{a}=\dfrac{2}{b}$

The second part follows from the colored part.

Comment: Proofs usually don't first assume the result given is true, then work backwards to show it holds true...

Comment: Ah, I got until the colored part, but I didn't divide by $abc$

Comment: @user1843145: In fact a one line argument could be given by just saying that since $\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{c}$ are in A.P., $a,b,c$ are in H.P and hence the expression for $b$ directly follows.

Comment: Yeah, @ user 170039  sorry I have not looked into harmonic progression

Comment: ^Agreed @user170039

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer to the first part; second part has been adequately answer by Zarrax.
[image]